# Jquery: "Expected Comma but found <character>" error in Netbeans/Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, netbeans

Following is code which is giving above error, in netbeans as well as eclipse:

```
$(".bandListing").autocomplete({
   source : [ ${bandnavn} ]
});
```

The error says:

1) Expected Comma but found {
source:[${bandnavn}]

2) Expected Comma but found ]
source:[${bandnavn}]

${bandnavn} is JSP object containing String of comma separated values which is put into array and assign to source. The code output is fine

Following is screenshot from Netbeans of same; could anyone guide me how to rectify the same?

[image]

If it could be fixed without do much changes, that will be helpful.

Comment: In which file you wrote that code (JS or JSP template)?

Comment: It is in JS file.

Comment: can you give us know structure and type of `${bandnavn}` ? f.e. console.log result

Comment: DId you tried with a `<c:out>`?

Answer (score 0):

Store the value returned `${bandnavn}` in a JavaScript variable, then use `split()` to create an array of string which can be supplied to `autocomplete`

```
var str = '${bandnavn}';
$(".bandListing").autocomplete({
   source : str.split(',')
});
```

Comment: That i have already done. Thanks for that but can't we solve above errors some way?

Comment: @fatherazrael, Assuming returned value is something like `a,b` if you can return string value wrapped in quotes i.e. `"a","b"` then you can solve the error. However Whats wrong with the above approach?